# Count amount by grouping list in java

Tags: java, list, count, grouping

i need to count total doctor transaction using an attribute id, and then total amount payment doctor using an attribute id from list.
how to resolve it? i'm stuck to count it.
please to tell

this is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class SandboxList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Doctor> doctors = new ArrayList<Doctor>();
        doctors.add(new Doctor("1726", "John", 10000.00));
        doctors.add(new Doctor("4321", "Max", 20000.00));
        doctors.add(new Doctor("1726", "John", 40000.00));
        doctors.add(new Doctor("4321", "Max", 2000.00));
        doctors.add(new Doctor("7765", "Sam", 50000.00));
        doctors.add(new Doctor("4321", "Max", 6000.00));

        /*  I want Output should be Like below
            ID : 1726   Name : John Total_payment : 50000.00  total_transaction : 2
            ID : 4321   Name : Max  Total_payment : 28000.00  total_transaction : 3
            ID : 7765   Name : Sam  Total_payment : 50000.00  total_transaction : 1

         */

        Map<String, List<Doctor>> groupedDoctors = new HashMap<String, List<Doctor>>();
        for (Doctor doctor: doctors) {
            String key = doctor.doctor_id;
            if (groupedDoctors.get(key) == null) {
                groupedDoctors.put(key, new ArrayList<Doctor>());
            }
            groupedDoctors.get(key).add(doctor);
        }

        Set<String> groupedDoctorsKeySet = groupedDoctors.keySet();
        for (String doctorId: groupedDoctorsKeySet) {
           List<Doctor> dctrs = groupedDoctors.get(doctorId);
           for (Doctor doctor : dctrs) {
                System.out.println("ID : "+doctor.doctor_id+"\t"+"Name : "+doctor.doctor_name+"\t"+"total_Payment : "+doctor.doctor_payment);
            }
        }


    }
}

class Doctor {

    String doctor_id;
    String doctor_name;
    Double doctor_payment;

    Doctor(String doctor_id, String doctor_name, Double doctor_payment) {

        this.doctor_id = doctor_id;
        this.doctor_name = doctor_name;
        this.doctor_payment = doctor_payment;

    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you have mixed the notion of doctors and payments, that's why you are facing this "merge" problem. Are you open to modify `Doctor`'s implementation in order to simplify your code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code for:

```
    for (String doctorId : groupedDoctorsKeySet) {
        List<Doctor> dctrs = groupedDoctors.get(doctorId);

        Double total_payment = 0d;
        String doctor_name = null;
        for (Doctor doctor : dctrs) {
            if (doctor_name == null) {
                doctor_name = doctor.doctor_name;
            }
            total_payment += doctor.doctor_payment;
        }
        Doctor doctor = new Doctor(doctorId, doctor_name, total_payment);
        System.out.println("ID : " + doctor.doctor_id + "\t" + "Name : " + doctor.doctor_name + "\ttotal_Payment : " + doctor.doctor_payment);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this after you group the doctors:

```
Set<String> groupedDoctorsKeySet = groupedDoctors.keySet();
for (String doctorId : groupedDoctorsKeySet)
{
    List<Doctor> dctrs = groupedDoctors.get(doctorId);

    if (dctrs != null && dctrs.size() > 0)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("ID : ").append(doctorId).append("\t").append("Name : ");
        sb.append(dctrs.get(0).doctor_name).append("\t").append("total_Payment : ");

        double total = 0;
        // sum the payment
        for (Doctor d : dctrs)
        {
            total += d.doctor_payment;
        }
        sb.append(total).append("\t").append("total_transaction : ");
        sb.append(dctrs.size());

        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

**Outputs**:

```
ID : 4321   Name : Max  total_Payment : 28000.0 total_transaction : 3
ID : 7765   Name : Sam  total_Payment : 50000.0 total_transaction : 1
ID : 1726   Name : John total_Payment : 50000.0 total_transaction : 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using what you already have you could update the grouped section to the below:

```
        Set<String> groupedDoctorsKeySet = groupedDoctors.keySet();
        for (String doctorId: groupedDoctorsKeySet) {
            List<Doctor> dctrs = groupedDoctors.get(doctorId);
            if (dctrs.size() <= 0) { continue; }
            Doctor doctor = dctrs.get(0); //These should all be the same doctor due to the key
            double totalPayment = 0.0;
            for(Doctor doc : dctrs){ totalPayment += doc.doctor_payment; }
            System.out.println("ID : " + doctor.doctor_id + "\tName : " + doctor.doctor_name
                    + "\ttotal_Payment : " + totalPayment + "\tNumber Of transactions: " + dctrs.size());
        }
```

=========================================================================
**Alternative Solution**

Alternatively, if the purpose of duplicating the doctors was to be able to examine each payment individually at some point in the future, you could have single Doctor's but with lists of payments. Exposing a method to update the doctor with new payment details

You would then be able to get the number of transactions from the size of that list and the Doctor object would be able to determine the total itself:

```
class Doctor {
    String doctor_id;
    String doctor_name;
    List<Double> doctor_payments = new ArrayList<>();

    Doctor(String doctor_id, String doctor_name, Double doctor_payment) {
        this.doctor_id = doctor_id;
        this.doctor_name = doctor_name;
        this.doctor_payments.add(doctor_payment);
    }

    public void processPayment(double paymentAmount){
        this.doctor_payments.add(paymentAmount);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        double totalPayment = 0.0;
        for(Double payment : doctor_payments){ totalPayment += payment; }

        return "ID : " + doctor_id + "\tName : " + doctor_name
            + "\ttotal_Payment : " + totalPayment + "\tNumber Of transactions: " + doctor_payments.size();
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
        Doctor john = new Doctor("1726", "John", 10000.00);
        john.processPayment(40000.00);
        System.out.println(john);
```

Output: `ID : 1726  Name : John total_Payment : 50000.0 Number Of transactions: 2`

Comment: incorrect syntax at here sir totalPayment += doc.doctor_payment;

Comment: These were two separate solutions, you shouldn't have gotten that error unless you merged them both. I'll edit the answer to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

I have used only 2 data structure  so that resources can be consume as less as much possible.

```
class Doctor {

String doctor_id;
String doctor_name;
Double doctor_payment;

Doctor(String doctor_id, String doctor_name, Double doctor_payment) {
    this.doctor_id = doctor_id;
    this.doctor_name = doctor_name;
    this.doctor_payment = doctor_payment;
}

public String getDoctor_id() {
    return doctor_id;
}

public String getDoctor_name() {
    return doctor_name;
}

public Double getDoctor_payment() {
    return doctor_payment;
}

public void setDoctor_id(String doctor_id) {
    this.doctor_id = doctor_id;
}

public void setDoctor_name(String doctor_name) {
    this.doctor_name = doctor_name;
}

public void setDoctor_payment(Double doctor_payment) {
    this.doctor_payment = doctor_payment;
}
/*
   HashCode() and equal() method is override because I want to identify the 
   element in collection on basis of ID's
 */

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Doctor other = (Doctor) obj;
    if (doctor_id == null) {
        if (other.doctor_id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!doctor_id.equals(other.doctor_id))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((doctor_id == null) ? 0 :   
             doctor_id.hashCode());
    return result;
}
}


public class SandboxList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       List<Doctor> doctors = new ArrayList<Doctor>();
    doctors.add(new Doctor("1726", "John", 10000.00));
    doctors.add(new Doctor("4321", "Max", 20000.00));
    doctors.add(new Doctor("1726", "John", 40000.00));
    doctors.add(new Doctor("4321", "Max", 2000.00));
    doctors.add(new Doctor("7765", "Sam", 50000.00));
    doctors.add(new Doctor("4321", "Max", 6000.00));

    Vector<Doctor> groupedDoctors = new Vector<Doctor>();


    Doctor loopVariable;
    int index;
    for (Doctor doctor : doctors) {
        index = groupedDoctors.indexOf(doctor);
        // -1 shows groupedDoctors doesn't contain of this doctor 
        if (-1!=index) {
            loopVariable = groupedDoctors.elementAt(index);
            groupedDoctors.removeElementAt(index);
            loopVariable.setDoctor_payment(doctor.getDoctor_payment() + loopVariable.getDoctor_payment());
            groupedDoctors.add(loopVariable);
        }
        else{
            groupedDoctors.addElement(doctor);
        }

    }

    for (Doctor doctor : groupedDoctors) {
        System.out.println("ID : " + doctor.doctor_id + "\t" + "Name : " +  
                            doctor.doctor_name + "\t"
                         + "total_Payment : " + doctor.doctor_payment);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use Vectors anymore. Also, your equals and hashCode methods are essentially broken because you are just considering the doctors ID.

Answer (score 0):

You may need the code like this:

```
Set<String> groupedDoctorsKeySet = groupedDoctors.keySet();
if (groupedDoctorsKeySet != null) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList(groupedDoctorsKeySet);
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                if (Long.valueOf(o1) < Long.valueOf(o2)) return -1;
                else if (Long.valueOf(01) == Long.valueOf(02)) return 0;
                else return 1;
            }
        });
        for (String doctorId: list) {
            List<Doctor> dctrs = groupedDoctors.get(doctorId);
            if (dctrs != null) {
                double sum = 0;
                String name = null;
                for (Doctor doctor : dctrs) {
                    if (name == null) name = doctor.doctor_name;
                    sum += doctor.doctor_payment;
                }
                System.out.println(String.format("ID : %s\tName : %s\tTotal_payment : %.2f  total_transaction : %d", new Object[]{doctorId, name, sum, dctrs.size()}));
            }

        }
    }
```

and the output is:

```
ID : 1726   Name : John Total_payment : 50000.00  total_transaction : 2
ID : 4321   Name : Max  Total_payment : 28000.00  total_transaction : 3
ID : 7765   Name : Sam  Total_payment : 50000.00  total_transaction : 1
```